# State machine using RxJava?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to go all in on RxJava and solve this problem I have with it, but it seems very unsuited for it, as RxJava seems to not want to deal with having any sort of state, rather only passing along events and mutating them to handle them.

The basic state machine behavior I'm trying to emulate with RxJava is this:

1. On app start event, wait for the next app pause.
2. On app pause event, start a 15 minute timer and wait for the next app resume.

   - If the app resumes within the timer, cancel it and go back to step 1.
3. On app resume event, if the 15 minute timer has elapsed, refresh and go back to step 1.

Comment: The way we have implemented some similar things is using RX as a kind of 1-way event bus, where the app puts events on the bus, and different Observers care about different events, and each keep their own state. That is our tracking architecture, with over a hundred different events and dozens of observers each handling a different tracking event - sometimes for different tracking platforms. I think keeping this state in RX, if possible, would be overly complicated - especially if you consider that you might have to persist the state for when your app's memory is wiped in the BG by the system.

Comment: Yeah, I think our app is similar. We've only switched over relatively recently, and there's still a lot of exploration for us on what is possible/should be done with Rx and vice versa.

Comment: I guess we went through a similar process, realizing along the way that "RX all the things" is not a good way to go. Aside from the really basic homespun event bus for tracking, for us the RX chains go only in 1 direction - from the Repository layer up through Interactors and to the Presenters, which subscribe and call the View methods directly. We haven't yet sorted out if/how the new ViewModel and Lifecycle arch stuff fits into that.

Comment: Just wanted to note that there's a simple state machine implementation over here: https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava2-extras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to implement a state machine in RxJava, it gets very ugly, very quickly. You can use the `switchMap()` operator to select some of the branching paths, and you can use several other operators to branch and merge.

Most of the issue is that state machine transitions tend to look more like `go to` than structured programming, and they tend not to resemble functional programming at all.

For similar reasons, it is quite difficult to create a fluent or functional description of any non-trivial state machine. There is an RxJava implementation of general state machines [RxFsm](https://github.com/furuholm/RxFsm), and it looks quite competent. You will have provide timers as external inputs, and other such work-arounds.

Here is code that implements your state machine, using some RxJava elements, and making some simplifying assumptions:

```
Observable<AppState> appStateObservable;
AtomicReference<Subscription> timerSubscription = new AtomicReference<>(Subscriptions.empty());

appStateObservable
  .doOnNext( state -> if ( state == START ) doStartup() )
  .filter( state -> state != START )
  .subscribe( state -> if ( state == PAUSE ) {
      timerSubscription.set( Observable.timer(15, MINUTES)
        .subscribe( timerSubscription.get().unsubscribe() ) );
    } else  if ( timerSubscription.get().isUnsubscribed() ) {
      refresh();
    } else {
      timerSubscription.get().unsubscribe();
    } );
```

It uses the `timerSubscription` subscription state to determine if the timer has fired, and, thus, perform the refresh.

Comment: Can you please tell why and how it gets ugly? I am implementing state machine in my project but only on a module/feature wise. I just want to understand in what way do you mean ugly.

Comment: The "ugliness" arises from several directions: 1) FSM inputs come from several sources and are of various types, 2) state transitions require moving to a different part of the observer chain, 3) error handling complicates all of the above.