# What would be the correct approach using Rx.NET to change how a message stream is handled according to rules applies to previous messages?

Tags: .net, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I have a stream of general "messages". It does not matter at this point what type, just messages in the sense of message queue or service bus messages.

This stream of messages is represented as an `IObservable<Message>`, which is subscribed to by a message handler, and this handler is supposed to be smart, adjusting how it deals with the messages according to the results of previous message processing.

So for example, let us say the message stream are inputs to a vending machine, such as "Press New Coffee", "Pay", "Add Sugar" and the message handler is supposed to yield output like a state machine would. The overall scenario is not quite the same as this, but the analogy works well enough.

My intuition tells me that a custom extension, akin to `.Scan`, altering output according to a function based on the history of the stream so far, would be the way to go. `.Scan` applies a function to both the input and some aggregator to yield a new result and update the aggregator. This stateful processing of a stream could be extended to a .StateMachine type Rx.NET extension.

This would allow workflows to be applied to streams.

However, this raises a number of question to which I would be grateful for any advice:

- I can't help feeling some self-doubt that this might be the wrong way of looking at things for Rx. Adding state machines to Rx feels like mixing imperative with functional programming. Are there purely Rx ways of (eg:) applying

> IF (previous message was X) THEN (now do A with new message) ELSE (now
>   do B with new message)

- Is there something out there already aimed at handling this (I read somewhere that MS have a tool set in the pipeline called Reactor that may also have orchestration, but I am uncertain where I read it or if it is correct)

Comment: You aren't exactly handling a stream of events, you are altering *one* state machine, one message at a time. This can be a single operator that changes some external state based on the incoming messages, not unlike `Sum`. All you need is to create an operator that subscribes to an input observable and posts to its subscribers based on its internal state.

Comment: If you search for `implement state machine with rx` you'll find many techniques, mainly in Java and Javascript, like [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065133/state-machine-using-rxjava) and  [this gist](https://gist.github.com/elandau/38a28ffab5ad6566f166). Note from the SO question: `While it is possible to implement a state machine in RxJava, it gets very ugly, very quickly.`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the comments. I ended up implementing it myself using the following Rx approach. A Conversation was a stream of ConversationStates, each of which embodied a stream of messages. Standard Rx operators like Concat and SelectMany allowed the Conversation to offer a flattened stream of messages. The state changes were actually messages themselves (StateChangeMessage), which triggered a kind of TakeUntil operator in the Conversation. Roughly like that. ConversationStates were partial classes in the Conversation.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This gave me a pretty powerful framework where I can describe protocols as Conversations with their states and connect them to a bus (Subject). The messages going into Conversations (from the bus) drive the outputs (to the bus) in this manner. I actually managed to implement some crypto base networking layers using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

The below-posted link is example of an F# agent that can respond differently based on both received message AND the internal state existing at the time the message is received...
I think this pattern/style (EDIT: of the CODE INSIDE the agent) can be translated to other messaging applications, the relevant mechanism is the combination of multiple states defined using the 'rec'/'and' F# keyword combination used for simultaneous recursive definitions, and the 'choosestate' function

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh297096.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

under the section "implementing a state machine"...the use of the F# agent (AKA 'mailboxprocessor' type) method 'Scan' is also necessary to override the linear ordered nature of the incoming message queue of an agent (please note this is the built-in queue, not the second queue explicitly defined in the agent as 'items', this second queue is where the items will be placed that are produced by processing the messages from the agent's incoming message queue), and be able to process messages out of the order in which they were received (please note this is not the Rx library's 'Scan', maybe the concept is related), as the empty/partially-full/full state of the internal data structure determines how the looping is altered

edit: I'm not proposing agents, I'm giving an example of a looping construct I've found useful and re-used several times in non-agent contexts...

Comment: Rx isn't agents. It's a completely different computing scenario (paradigm if you will) - event streams. While you can use one to emulate the other, the result will be far more cumbersome - think nails and Philips screws. For event stream processing, Rx is a *higher* level concept than agents

Comment: Yes, I dont think my answer implies they are equivalent, hence my statement "I think this pattern/style can be translated to other messaging applications"...I meant the logic inside the agent, of processing incoming messages based on existing internal state, can be applied outside of the agent concept...I just edited to say that explicitly...

Comment: This cna't be used as an answer in the first place. It's a long comment about *another* concurrency technique.

Comment: The logic inside the agent is not specific to agents...I have re-written it as a standard class...It has nothing to do with the agent paradigm.

Comment: It's a way of changing loop structure based on an input.

Comment: Loop techniques when the question is about SQL. In fact, that's the example I had in mind but chose nails vs screws instead.